# Group Names from One column to another column in Excel

Tags: excel, grouping

I have an excelsheet with one column F with different values for example:

`Terry, Monica, Thomas, Eric, Susan, Martha, Gary`

and so on. Approx 5000 rows with 250 different values.

Now I want to group these values in column A.

For example:

- Group1: Thomas, Gary
- Group2: Eric, Susan
- Group3: Monica, Terry, Martha

and so on.

I dont want to sort and filter the values because I fill the sheet with new values everyday. I have thought about an IF statement but that doesn´t work.

Any ideas?

Comment: *I fill the sheet with new values everyday* - are they totally new names, or are they the same names in a different order?

Comment: What are the rules for putting one value into another category? What have you tried so far?

Comment: could you show some test data and expected results.  You can probably use a vlookup to another table that has a list of names and desired group.

Comment: Are it fixed groups, or do the groups also vary on daily basis?

Comment: I have tried If F1="Thomas";"Group1";""; and that works with one value but if I want to add if (F1="Thomas";"Group1";"") if(F1="Eric";"Group2";""). But this doesnt work and it will be a long, long formula and many If statement. So I wonder If there is Another way.

Comment: There are fixed Groups but sometime I have new name that I have to add.

Comment: @Scott Holzman I import the names from I file to my excel sheet and when the names get imported to excel I want them to be in the same Group as yesterday, automaticly. Mostly the same names but in different orders. Everyday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a small table that has the names and the desired groups:

[image]

Then just use VLOOKUP to equate the list with the desired group:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,$H:$I,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That what exactly what I wanted. With best regards Thomas

Comment: Feel free to mark as correct.  click the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want column A to "detect" the available values from column F and generate groups from that.  Although it might be possible to create a function that accomplishes what you want, Sort and Filter might turn out to be the most *convenient* tools for doing this.

If you [enable the Developer tab](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608625.aspx), you can click Record Macro, assign a Shortcut Key, and then perform the chore of sorting and filtering the values one time.  Tomorrow, when you refill the same sheet with new values, you can simply run the macro again in an instant with its shortcut key.

If what you want to do turns out to be too sophisticated for a macro to successfully perform the correct actions the same way every day, you can customize the automation with Visual Basic for Applications (VBA).  The quickest way to jump into VBA is to complete the recording of a brief macro, then click the Macro button on the developer tab again, then select your new macro from the list and click Edit to see the underlying code.

To have folks help you with complex functions or VBA, however, you'd probably need to share more details about the layout of your spreadsheet and exactly how you'd like the output to appear.